# Отмена стилизации объекта

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при помощи инлайнового стиля отменить стандартную стилизацию HTML-объекта. В данном случае HTML-объектом является `button`. Для демонстрации проблемы прикреплено изображение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не очень понятен вопрос, что именно требуется, убрать стандартный стиль с кнопки?

Comment: Да, убрать стандартный CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
  }
</style>
```

если требуется то отступы также убрать

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Инлайново:

```
<button style="background: none; border: none; padding: 0;">...</button>
```

Либо обнулить эти свойства в том классе, который вы присваиваете кнопке (или элементам слева).